# Specify the MySql assembly for NHibernate?

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, assemblies

We have built the MySql connector from source and changed the assembly name to OurCompany.MySql.Data.

Also, I am exploring ORM's for the first time and came across NHibernate. After configuring everything and mapping my first test class I am at a point where our renamed MySql connector is now a problem. Is there a way I can point NHibernate to our renamed assembly?

** edit heres my config **

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">
            NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="connection.provider">
            NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
        </property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">
           Server=192.168.2.5;Database=TomTest;User ID=webuser;Password=webuser
        </property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
           NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
        </property>
        <!-- HBM Mapping Files -->
        <mapping assembly="MyAssembly"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code of [MySqlDataDriver](https://github.com/mausch/NHibernate/blob/master/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Driver/MySqlDataDriver.cs). It's trivial to write a ReflectionBasedDriver that is exactly like the MySqlDataDriver but only differs in the assembly name (the second parameter in the constructor). Then plug your driver in the `connection.driver_class` property (use its fully qualified type name)

Comment: I dont have the NHibernate source, but it wont hurt me to get it.. thank you.

Comment: I linked to the source, that file is all you need.